# ASLA "aplay" operattion not permitted

Tags: raspberry-pi, alsa, raspberry-pi2, debian-based

I'm using a RPB2 I'm trying to ouput a sound  .wav by the analog output, but when I try aplay it says "errror -1 operattion not permited" ... I checked the groups and my user belongs to, also this my "asound.state"

```
state.ALSA {
    control.1 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'PCM Playback Volume'
            value -1725
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type INTEGER
                    count 1
                    range '-10239 - 400'
                    dbmin -9999999
                    dbmax 400
                    dbvalue.0 -1725
            }
    }
    control.2 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'PCM Playback Switch'
            value true
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type BOOLEAN
                    count 1
            }
    }
    control.3 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'PCM Playback Route'
            value 1
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type INTEGER
                    count 1
                    range '0 - 2'
            }
    }
}
```

Don't know what it's wrong. 
PD: I can't do update or upgrade since I'm using an specific OS version

Comment: *What* group did you check?